# Solve a system of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I cannot find a way to solve the following polynomial equation system

$$\begin{cases}-3x^{2}+y^{2}-2xy-\alpha_{1}x+\alpha_{0}=0\\
-x^{2}+3y^{2}+2xy-\beta_{1}y+\beta_{0}=0\end{cases}$$

Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{0}$, $\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{0}$ are any real numbers.

Comment: Are you expecting a closed form for any $\alpha_1,\alpha_0,\beta_1,\beta_0$ ? If it exists, it would me the nicest Xmas present for me. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-x%5E2%2B3y%5E2%2B2xy-b_1+y%2Bb_0%3D0%2C+-3x%5E2%2By%5E2-2xy-a_1+x%2Ba_0%3D0+for+x%2Cy) can do it but the solution is horrible. Merry Xmas!

Comment: @lhf. Thank you so much ! I never had a so nice present for Xmas (or any other day !). This is just pure beauty ! Merry Xmas. Cheers :-)

Comment: hey, guys, come on. If you know how to get the closed form, please tell me. That would be the nicest Xmas present for me.

Comment: @congmingniao, click on the WA link in my comment above.

Comment: @lhf  thank you. Do you know how to use WA solve this equation system subject to some other conditions like $-6x-2y-\alpha_{1}<0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two equations in two variables, a neater way is to eliminate one variable using ***resultants***. (Click on this [WA link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Collect%5BResultant%5B-3x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20-%202x%20y%20-%20a_1%20x%20%2B%20a_0%2C-x%5E2%20%2B%203y%5E2%20%2B%202x%20y%20-%20b_1%20y%20%2B%20b_0%2C%20y%5D%2Cx%2CFactor%5D).) Eliminating $y$, one gets (rather suprisingly) a ***cubic*** in $x$,

$$ (32 a_1+32 b_1)x^3+ (10 a_1 b_1+9 a_1^2-32 a_0-3 b_1^2+32 b_0)x^2+ (-a_1 b_1^2-10 a_0 b_1+6 a_1 b_0-18 a_0 a_1-2 b_0 b_1)x+(a_0 b_1^2-6 a_0 b_0+9 a_0^2+b_0^2)=0$$

Thus, for any real $a_0,\,a_1,\,b_0,\,b_1$ you use, at least one of $x,y$ will also be real. The cubic can be put in the form,

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$

and a [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20ax%5E3%2Bbx%5E2%2Bcx%2Bd%20%3D%200%20for%20x) for $x$ is easily found. Unfortunately, you have four parameters, so the end symbolic result will still be messy, though it will not be too bad for numerical examples.

$\color{green}{(Edit)}$

Example: Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_0 = 4,\,3$ and $\beta_1,\beta_0 = 6,\,1$. So,

$$-3x^2 + y^2 - 2x y - 4x + 3 = 0\\-x^2 + 3y^2 + 2x y - 6y + 1 = 0$$

[Eliminate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B-3x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20-%202x%20y%20-%204x%20%2B%203%2C%20-x%5E2%20%2B%203y%5E2%20%2B%202x%20y%20-%206y%20%2B%201%2C%20x%5D%5D) $x$ using WA and we get,

$$4 - 8 y - 113 y^2 + 80 y^3=0\tag1$$

and [eliminating](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B-3x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20-%202x%20y%20-%204x%20%2B%203%2C%20-x%5E2%20%2B%203y%5E2%20%2B%202x%20y%20-%206y%20%2B%201%2C%20y%5D%5D) $y$,

$$43 - 132 x + 53 x^2 + 80 x^3=0\tag2$$

However, $(1)$ and $(2)$ will have three solutions each, so one still has to find the correct pairs $x_i,y_i$ by numerical testing. Both are 3-real root cubics, and the correct pairs are,

$$x_1,\, y_1 \approx -1.767833,\; -0.209114\\
x_2,\, y_2 \approx 0.515306,\; 0.1640421\\
x_3,\, y_3 \approx 0.590026,\; 1.457572$$

Of course, one can then find the exact expressions for the $x_i,y_i$ by using the cubic formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know nothing about how to use resultants to solve equation system. Could you recommend any easy reference for me to read about resultants and make me clear how does your proposed process work ?

Comment: @congmingniao: A gentle introduction to _resultants_ would be the usual sources: [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Resultant.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). I've also edited my answer to include an example. Just click on the WolframAlpha links to see the commands.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. Happy new year~